# JUnit code coverage not covered completly

Tags: junit

I wrote test cases for below class but problem is still its not getting covered 100% and i mentioned not coverage code with > symbol in my below class can some one suggest me what can i do for cover remaining code

### Repository class

```
    public RowMapperServerResponse insertproductDetails(RowMapperServerResponse rowMapperServerResponse) {
            try {
                int insertRow = jdbcTemplate.update(
                        "insert into Master_Circuit (id_type,product,seq_no,name,dependent_count,create_time) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)",
                        rowMapperServerResponse.getId_type(), rowMapperServerResponse.getProduct(),
                        rowMapperServerResponse.getSeq_no(), rowMapperServerResponse.getName(),
                        rowMapperServerResponse.getDependent_count(), rowMapperServerResponse.getCreate_time());

        *
> if (insertRow != 0) {
>                       return rowMapperServerResponse;
>                   }
>               } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e) {
>                   return null;
>               }

*
            return null;
        }
```

### test cases

```
@Test
    public void insertproductDetailsTest() {

        baaisnEvcIdMSRepository.insertproductDetails(rowResponse());

        Mockito.when(jdbcTemplate.update(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString(),
                Mockito.anyInt(), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyInt(), Mockito.any())).thenReturn(1);

        Mockito.verify(jdbcTemplate, Mockito.times(1)).update(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString(),
                Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyInt(), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyInt(), Mockito.any());
    }

    @Test
    public void insertproductDetailsEmptyTest() {

        baaisnEvcIdMSRepository.insertproductDetails(rowResponse());

        Mockito.when(jdbcTemplate.update(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString(),
                Mockito.anyInt(), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyInt(), Mockito.any())).thenReturn(0);

        Mockito.verify(jdbcTemplate, Mockito.times(1)).update(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString(),
                Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyInt(), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyInt(), Mockito.any());
    }

    private RowMapperServerResponse rowResponse() {

        RowMapperServerResponse rowMapperServerResponse = mock(RowMapperServerResponse.class);
        Mockito.when(rowMapperServerResponse.getMaster_kit_id()).thenReturn(464662);
        Mockito.when(rowMapperServerResponse.getId_type()).thenReturn("EMSsample");
        Mockito.when(rowMapperServerResponse.getProduct()).thenReturn("sample");
        Mockito.when(rowMapperServerResponse.getSeq_no()).thenReturn(36316);
        Mockito.when(rowMapperServerResponse.getName()).thenReturn("TLS");
        Mockito.when(rowMapperServerResponse.getDependent_count()).thenReturn(0);
        Mockito.when(rowMapperServerResponse.getCreate_time()).thenReturn(new Date());

        return rowMapperServerResponse;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest just putting a breakpoint inside the `if` block.
If there code is not covered, obviously no test enters that block.

One possible issue would be that you call the `baaisnEvcIdMSRepository.insertproductDetails` and only afterthat (next line in the test) specify the expectations in Mockito. I'm not a mockito expert, but during the "Subject Under Test" execution how Mockito can know that you expect it to return 0 / 1? If it uses some defaults, it can always return 0, so if branch won't be executed.